# Adding a fixed sticky nav bar which doesn't cover the image

Tags: css, responsive-design, bootstrap-4, navbar, sticky

I am trying to create a responsive bootstrap sticky nav to go above the carousel. However the navbar covers the top proportion of the image. How can i change so that it sticks above for desktop/mobile, but doesn't overflow onto the image itself.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-primary fixed-top navbar " color-on-scroll="400">

            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-translate">
                    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navigation" aria-controls="navigation-index" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                        <span><i class="fas fa-bars" style="
                                 color: #ffffff;
                                 "></i></span>
                    </button>
                    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/chicago.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">

                </div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navigation" >
                    <ul class="navbar-nav">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="scrollToDownload()">
                                <p>Location</p>
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. See: How to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: 
I added  body { padding-top: 90px; }

Answer (score 1):

Give margin-top:100px or what is the height of you navigation menu, applying that height to the slider parent div class and it works fine.